# How do i get table name and column name using sequence name in postgres?

Tags: postgresql-11

I know the sequence name but I don't know the table name and column name of it.
So please help me how to find it.

Comment: can anyone help me with the code to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's a sequence that is owned by a column e.g. because the column is defined as `serial` or `identity` then you can get that information by looking at pg_depend and join that to `pg_class` (and others)

```
select tbl.relname as table_name, 
       col.attname as column_name
from pg_class s
  join pg_namespace sn on sn.oid = s.relnamespace 
  join pg_depend d on d.refobjid = s.oid and d.refclassid='pg_class'::regclass 
  join pg_attrdef ad on ad.oid = d.objid and d.classid = 'pg_attrdef'::regclass
  join pg_attribute col on col.attrelid = ad.adrelid and col.attnum = ad.adnum
  join pg_class tbl on tbl.oid = ad.adrelid 
  join pg_namespace ts on ts.oid = tbl.relnamespace 
where s.relkind = 'S'
  and s.relname = 'your_sequence_name_her'
  and d.deptype in ('a', 'n');
```

Another option is to look at the default value of the columns and check if it contains the sequence name:

```
select tbl.relname as table_name, 
       col.attname as column_name
from pg_attrdef ad
  join pg_attribute col on col.attrelid = ad.adrelid and col.attnum = ad.adnum
  join pg_class tbl on tbl.oid = ad.adrelid
where pg_get_expr(ad.adbin, ad.adrelid) like '%your_sequence_name_here%'
```

This would also work for sequences that are not owned by a column.

Comment: Thanks for the query. I tried executing both the queries,                                                      "select tbl.relname as table_name, 
       col.attname as column_name
from pg_attrdef ad 
  join pg_attribute col on col.attrelid = ad.adrelid and col.attnum = ad.adnum
  join pg_class tbl on tbl.oid = ad.adrelid
where adsrc like '%course_course_id_seq%' "
but it results                                              "Successfully run. Total query runtime: 95 msec. 0 rows affected."

Answer (score 1):

Slight improvisation using @a_horse_with_no_name's answer. The below query will also give the schema name and sequence name. So, this gives you the data with schema,table,column and sequence names as single result

```
select ts.nspname as object_schema,
        tbl.relname as table_name, 
       col.attname as column_name,
       s.relname   as sequence_name
from pg_class s
  join pg_namespace sn on sn.oid = s.relnamespace 
  join pg_depend d on d.refobjid = s.oid and d.refclassid='pg_class'::regclass 
  join pg_attrdef ad on ad.oid = d.objid and d.classid = 'pg_attrdef'::regclass
  join pg_attribute col on col.attrelid = ad.adrelid and col.attnum = ad.adnum
  join pg_class tbl on tbl.oid = ad.adrelid 
  join pg_namespace ts on ts.oid = tbl.relnamespace 
where s.relkind = 'S'
--  and s.relname = 'your_sequence_name_here'
  and d.deptype in ('a', 'n');
```